# How do I script "python /home/pi/pipresents/pipresents.py -p pp_mediashow_1p3" in python

Tags: python

I want to make a presentation on a raspberry pi with pipresents and my problem is that I need to know how to code "python /home/pi/pipresents/pipresents.py -p pp_mediashow_1p3" in a python script.

In the /home/pi/pp_home/pp_mediashow_1p3 directoy are three different .json scripts to configure the presentation and the pipresents.py scripts starts the presentation.

I know how to execute the pipresents.py script, but how do I code "-p pp_mediashow_1p3"?

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run("/home/pi/pipresents/pipresents.py")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add parameters by passing a list of strings to the `run()` call. There are other ways to do that, but the array is good practice against certain types of exploits.

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["/home/pi/pipresents/pipresents.py", "-p", "pp_mediashow_1p3"])
```

Check the [subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) for a load of options.